# typescript not throwing error when passed an object that should throw

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have some code that I expect to throw an error that isn't in typescript and I'm not sure why. I have the following code in a react native project:

```
  const styles = {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
  } as const

  return <View style={styles} />
```

This is all well and good. However, if I add an invalid style to `styles`:

```
  const styles = {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    invalidStyle: 'bla'
  } as const

  return <View style={styles} />
```

Typescript does not throw an error.

This works (throws an error) if I put the styles directly on the `style` prop on `View`:

```
  return <View style={{
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    invalidStyle: 'bla'
  }} />
```

I correctly get `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'randomProps' does not exist in type 'ViewStyle | RecursiveArray<Falsy | ViewStyle | RegisteredStyle<ViewStyle>>'.`

Is there anything I can do to make sure I get this error in the non-direct assignment of styles?

Answer (score 1):

Please try explicit specification of the style type.

```
const styles: CSSProperties = {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    invalidStyle: 'bla'
  } as const
```

Then typescript will understand what to validate during initialization of the variable.

Comment: You'll probably want the React Native version `const styles: ViewStyle = {...}`

Comment: This does not work, I get the same behavior as I'm currently getting in the above example.

Comment: The error will be at the initialization of `styles`, not its usage.

Comment: ah, this is true. The problem is in my actual code I can't do this in the same way as I break keys off the object between creation and use.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the type of your `styles` const is a simple object, not a Stylesheet object, so it doesn't know what style values are appropriate. To fix that, define your styles like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     viewStyle: {
         flexGrow: 1,
         width: "100%",
         invalidStyle: "bla",
     },
});

return <View style={styles.viewStyle} />
```

Comment: This also does not work. I'm surprised to find I can put any values I want in `StyleSheet.create` without typescript complaining.

Comment: I guess in theory these are suppose to be checked on the `View` but in the case the same thing happens as happens with my code above and it just lets anything through